# Deprecation Warning Python mysql connector

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the python mysql connector with sqlalchemy.
I try to use this code to truncate a table:

```
 session = db.Session()

 session.execute('''TRUNCATE TABLE Orders''')
 session.commit()
```

But I receive this warning.

python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py:506: DeprecationWarning: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN will be required for '#' formats
self._cmysql.query(query,

I receive this issue also for other queries. The provided example is just for being an example.

Why exactly do I get this warning?

Answer (score 1):

> Why exactly do I get this warning?

Probably you are using mysql-connector before version 1.4.3 when they added [PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macros](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/v1.4.3/MySQLdb/_mysql.c#L37)

Also, some modules [like unittest by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner) shows DeprecationWarning, PendingDeprecationWarning, ResourceWarning and ImportWarning even if they are ignored by default.

**More info:**

[Starting from Python 3.8](https://bugs.python.org/issue36381) it will Raise a warning *for # use without PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN* in Python C API if Macros PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN was not defined before including Python.h.

https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/c-api/arg.html#strings-and-buffers

> For all # variants of formats (s#, y#, etc.), the type of the length
> argument (int or Py_ssize_t) is controlled by defining the macro
> PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN before including Python.h. If the macro was defined,
> length is a Py_ssize_t rather than an int. This behavior will change
> in a future Python version to only support Py_ssize_t and drop int
> support. It is best to always define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN.

Comment: The OP was referencing the `mysql-connector-python` package not `pymysql` . . . as of June 2021 the latest version of `mysql-connector-python` (8.0.25) still produces this deprecation warning.